# Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server

Tags: server, apache2

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor pres
   Active: **failed** (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-07-08 22:32:36 SAST; 18
  Process: 18097 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/

Jul 08 22:32:36 anonymous apachectl[18097]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reli
Jul 08 22:32:36 anonymous apachectl[18097]: (98)Address already in use: AH00
Jul 08 22:32:36 anonymous apachectl[18097]: (98)Address already in use: AH00
Jul 08 22:32:36 anonymous apachectl[18097]: no listening sockets available, 
Jul 08 22:32:36 anonymous apachectl[18097]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jul 08 22:32:36 anonymous apachectl[18097]: Action 'start' failed.
Jul 08 22:32:36 anonymous apachectl[18097]: The Apache error log may have mo
Jul 08 22:32:36 anonymous systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exite
Jul 08 22:32:36 anonymous systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'e
Jul 08 22:32:36 anonymous systemd[1]: **Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server**
lines 1-15/15 (END)
```

Comment: Hi Thors and welcome to askUbuntu! Add the output (at least the last lines) of your `/var/log/apache2/error.log` to your post. Resize your window or pipe the output with`tee` to a file, so that you can post the whole linen when restarting apache2!

Comment: You don't happen to have *another* web server already listening on ports 80 and 443, do you?

Comment: Please check first : `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: And how many web server installed in your system?

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your response [Mon Jul 09 19:20:48.240466 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1330:tid 140604777876416] AH00489: Apache/2.4.33 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.0g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 09 19:20:48.240633 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1330:tid 140604777876416] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Comment: Hello AlexP I did a search via aptitude in konsole and it seems to be showing a few installations of apache2 but I am not sure how to interpret the data shown. I am unable to copy/paste in aptitude. 

Also I did a netstat to find out whats using port 80  

netstat -an | grep ":80"

tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN

Comment: I also didnt have ssh installed I have now done that. I'm using ubuntu 18.10 by the way. Im now setting up a firewall. Hope this info helps.

Comment: Ok I seemed to have made some progress but now this appears...Jul 09 22:07:18 anonymous systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jul 09 22:07:18 anonymous apachectl[12038]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to
Jul 09 22:07:18 anonymous systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
lines 1-13/13 (END)

Answer (score 3):

The reason Apache fails to start is because something is already listening on the port/ip combination.  The log entries of "Address already in use" indicate this.

You need to identify what other service is running on those ports and then go and shut it off before turning on Apache.

However, since your log snippets **ONLY** are partial (and not from `sudo systemctl -l status apache2` so we can see all the actual useful information in large form, or from `/var/log/apache2/error.log` directly), we can't really point you at which application(s) to look at since we can't determine the ports in use (my assumption is Port 80, in which case `sudo ss -ntlp 'sport = 80'` will get us a better idea of what is already listening on Port 80.  Please replace '80' with whatever other port is actually in use according to the long log data, which is cut off in what you pasted here.)