# Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server on Ubuntu 18.4

Tags: server, apache2

I've seen this common issue discussed here before and tried everything but none works for me. like [Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053328/failed-to-start-the-apache-http-server) and https://superuser.com/questions/1522288/failed-to-start-the-apache-http-server

**ATTEMPTED**

- I've changed the port of Apache in case I run on duplicate port but it still not work.
- I've tried install Apache again and it still not work.

I don't know what else to look at

```
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-07-10 11:09:56 +07; 12min ago

៧ 10 11:09:56 moniroth-ThinkPad-T450s systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
៧ 10 11:09:56 moniroth-ThinkPad-T450s apachectl[969]: apache2: Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/sites-enable
៧ 10 11:09:56 moniroth-ThinkPad-T450s apachectl[969]: Action 'start' failed.
៧ 10 11:09:56 moniroth-ThinkPad-T450s apachectl[969]: The Apache error log may have more information.
៧ 10 11:09:56 moniroth-ThinkPad-T450s systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
៧ 10 11:09:56 moniroth-ThinkPad-T450s systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
៧ 10 11:09:56 moniroth-ThinkPad-T450s systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

**EDIT:** After running the command `apachectl configtest` I got this message

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/your_domain.com.conf: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/your_domain.com.conf:1: <VirtualHost> was not closed. Action 'configtest' failed. The Apache error log may have more information.
```

and here's what I have in the *your_domain.com.conf* file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@opencart.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/opencart/
     ServerName opentcart.com ServerAlias www.opencart.com <Directory /var/www/html/opencart/> Options FollowSymlinks AllowOverride All Order allow,deny allow from all </Directory> ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The provided output of `systemctl status apache2` is incomplete. Please read the second line `10 11:09:56 moniroth-ThinkPad-T450s apachectl[969]: apache2: Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/sites-enable` probably there is unnecessary character at the first line of some virtual host .conf file.

Comment: you may also test your configuration file with `apachectl configtest` AND please [edit] your question to provide the concerned config file

Comment: @cmak.fr I have updated my question. Please take a look, I'm really desperate for help

Comment: According to the test output message, it does not find the closing tag `</VirtualHost>`. Add carriage returns : one directive one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtualhost config file needs rework

From

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@opencart.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/opencart/
     ServerName opentcart.com ServerAlias www.opencart.com <Directory /var/www/html/opencart/> Options FollowSymlinks AllowOverride All Order allow,deny allow from all </Directory> ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined </VirtualHost>
```

To

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@opencart.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/opencart/
     ServerName opentcart.com
     ServerAlias www.opencart.com
     <Directory /var/www/html/opencart/>
        Options FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
     </Directory>
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The server started now. Thank you